# Kensington Expert Mouse Drag button

Tags: mouse, xinput

I want to change my button mapping and add a drag function

```
:~$ xinput list-props 10
Device 'Kensington USB/PS2 Wheel Mouse ':
    Device Enabled (148):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (150): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Accel Speed (285): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (286): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Profiles Available (287):    1, 1
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled (288):   1, 0
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (289):   1, 0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (290):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (291):   0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (270): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (271):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (272):    0, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (292): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (293): 0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (294):    0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (295):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (296):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Button Scrolling Button (297): 2
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (298): 2
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (299):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (300):    0
    Device Node (273):  "/dev/input/event4"
    Device Product ID (274):    1149, 4098
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (301):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (302):   1
```

if I add drag function

xinput -set-prop 10 301 1

only first button is drag function but It must be 3th or 4th button.
what must I do?

thanks

Comment: SOLUTION   xinput set-prop 10 301 9 3

Answer (score 1):

The way it works is like this:

```
xinput -set-prop 11 299 3 1
```

Ignore the 11 and the 299 which are specific to my computer, but in this case it's saying 3 is the lock button for 1.

You can also make a button its own lock button like:

```
xinput -set-prop 11 299 1 1
```

For more info check `man libinput` under the option "DragLockButtons".

Comment: For both meta and button pair configuration, the button numbers are device button numbers, i.e. the ButtonMapping applies after drag lock.